# highcharts: Add marker to a x-range chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to create a dumbbell chart using highcharts.

I used x-range chart for this

here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/thushara07/nLkxa0wr/15/

```
 series: [{
       // name: 'Project 3',
        // pointPadding: 0,
        // groupPadding: 0,
        //borderColor: 'gray',
        pointWidth: 5,
        data: [{
            x: 32,
            x2: 33,
            y: 0,
         //   partialFill: 0.25
        }, {

            x: 44,
            x2:45,
            y: 1
        }, {
            x:30,
            x2: 32,
            y: 2
        }],
        dataLabels: {
        align: 'left',
            enabled: true

        }
    }]
```

*expected output:* I want to show markers for each line created as shown
(https://images.app.goo.gl/LAKQBdsaKBH2hjS59
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by adding additional `scatter` series that is linked to `x-range`:

**Code:**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    categories: ['Prototyping', 'Development', 'Testing'],
    reversed: true
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'xrange',
    pointWidth: 5,
    id: 'main',
    data: [{
      x: 32,
      x2: 33,
      y: 0
    }, {
      x: 44,
      x2: 45,
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: 30,
      x2: 32,
      y: 2
    }],
    dataLabels: {
      align: 'center',
      enabled: true
    }
  }, {
    type: 'scatter',
    linkedTo: 'main',
    marker: {
        radius: 5
    },
    data: [{
        x: 32,
      y: 0,
      color: 'red'
    }, {
        x: 33,
      y: 0,
      color: 'grey'
    }, {
        x: 44,
      y: 1,
      color: 'red'
    }, {
        x: 45,
      y: 1,
      color: 'grey'
    }, {
        x: 30,
      y: 2,
      color: 'red'
    }, {
        x: 32,
      y: 2,
      color: 'grey'
    }]
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4qj89cog/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.linkedTo